# How to save a picture to a specific file after using OpenCV to take it?

Tags: python, windows, image, opencv

I use Python 3 and Windows. Currently, all my program can do is take a picture and display it, but I want to be able to save it to a specific destination. Here is the program:

```
# import the opencv and numpy libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np


# define a video capture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

while(True):

    cv2.imshow('img1',frame)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('y')):
        cv2.imwrite('images/c1.png', frame)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

cap.release()
```

Edit: BTW I'm new to Python and OpenCV so this code is mostly someone else's (forgot who so I can't cite, sorry).

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite)? You seem to be already saving the image with imwrite. Is that now working?

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen Yeah it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to move the line with `cap.read()` into the loop, after `while` statement if you want to capture repeatedly.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I only want to capture once, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You are currently writing the image to a file 'images/c1.png'. You can change this to an absolute path where you want to save the image i.e. `C:/Users/User/Pictures/c1.png` or you can set the current working directory to a different folder with `os.chdir('desired location')` so that it saves all images to that particular location (in this case it will save the image as 'images/c1.png' in that location).

Comment: Does my program need to be in the same location of where I want to save my image? The first method isn't working for me.

Comment: No need, until you won't provide the full path of your desired location.